# Net7 JWT Null Reference when publishing Blazor WASM Project?

Tags: azure, identity, blazor-webassembly, duende-identity-server, .net-7.0

so I've been working in the Net7 preview and have been trying to deploy a WASM project with identity and authentication which works fine locally. When I deploy the website 500s and digging into some of the logs, I get:

```
2022-11-07T13:42:28.854805951Z fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
2022-11-07T13:42:28.854856853Z       Exception occurred while processing message.
2022-11-07T13:42:28.854865053Z       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2022-11-07T13:42:28.856255318Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
2022-11-07T13:42:28.856286120Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

In my Program.cs I have

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
    .AddJwtBearer()
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

I've been trying to follow different Duende guides but even when I eventually get it to run locally, I still get the same error. I've tried removing the JWT lines in `AddAuthentication()` and that also did not seem to help.

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` and `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Sure, 

here is the appsettings - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EvilGamerX/Stuffy/master/Stuffy.Website/Server/appsettings.json

and the csproj - https://github.com/EvilGamerX/Stuffy/blob/master/Stuffy.Website/Server/Stuffy.Website.Server.csproj

Comment: I have deployed the App and even Iam getting 500 error.To know more about the issue, Navigate to KUDU Console,edit the `web.config` file - `stdoutLogEnabled=false` to `true`.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5rzY.png)

Comment: A new log file will be created in `LogFiles` folder.

Comment: For me the issue is with `Duende software`.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the stdout log to generate, but that might be because I've deployed it as a docker image on a linux system, but the docker log file I did get from the logstream was was an `AuthenticationHandler` problems with `Duende Middleware` throwing it.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have on your appsettings.json

> ```
> "IdentityServer": {
> "Key": {
>   "Type": "Development"
> }   },
> ```

Change the type to the correct one.